# len(n) command not working properly (Python)

Tags: python, list, function, append

I'm working on a program that gives discounts pending the fulfillment of  conditions:

```
If number of purchases > 4 give a 20% discount where the type of purchase is not a pet.
```

My list appends itself from user input, and I created a separate integer to keep track of the number of elements in the list, however, when I print that integer, the value is always 0. In order to progress further into this program, I need the integer to properly hold the correct value. Here is my code so far. I'm a beginner, so it's a little messy.

```
prices=[]
isPet=[]
nItems = len(prices)

def discount(prices, isPet, nItems):
    while True: 
        price=input("Enter the price, (-1 to quit): ") 
        prices.append(price)
        pet=input("Is it a pet? (Y/N, or -1 to quit) ")
        isPet.append(pet)
        if prices[-1] == "-1" and isPet[-1] == "-1":
            prices = prices[:-1]
            isPet = isPet[:-1]
            break
    print(nItems)
    if nItems > 4 and isPet == "N":
        discount = sum(prices)*0.8
        print("The discount is: ", discount)

discount(prices, isPet, nItems)
```

I printed nItems on line 16 to see if it was properly storing the len(prices) and that's where I found out it was printing 0

Comment: `nItems` is calculated at the start, and never updated. `nItems` is an integer, not the original expression and the `len()` function is not called again just because you print the value.

Comment: `nItems` is the _result_ of calling `len`. Once you call `len`, it returns a result and shuts down. It's not sitting in the background keeping track of your list and updating the variable somehow.

Comment: Were you expecting `nItems` to become a dynamic property or spreadsheet cell or something like that, whose value is always whatever `len(prices)` happens to be at the moment, instead of becoming a name for whatever `len(prices)` was at the time it was created? If so: most programming languages, including Python, don't work that way. You might be interested in _why_ they don't from a design point of view, or from the point of view of how variables work under the covers, or in what languages do have those kinds of variables.

Comment: On the other hand, if this was just a simple "oops, forgot to update `nItems` later", never mind.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you executed the `len()` function at the top, when the list is still empty:

```
prices=[]
# ...
nItems = len(prices)
```

Calling `len()` produces a result, here the integer `0`, and the name `nItems` is then set to reference that result.

Python does not store anything about how the value a name references was produced, `nItems` only references the integer, not that the integer was produced from a call to the function `len()` applied to the list `prices`. Until you assign something different to `nItems`, it'll keep pointing to `0`.

You then call `discount()`, and in the function print `nItems`. It still references `0`, and so that results in `0` being printed.

If you wanted to print the length of `prices`, you need to call `len()` again. Either print the result of the `len()` call:

```
print(len(prices))
```

or assign the result to a variable and then print that variable:

```
price_count = len(prices)
print(price_count)
```